# .NET and Active Directory - System.Exception: General access denied error

Tags: .net, active-directory

I keep getting this error when I try to create a new user.

This is the part of my code that give me the error:

```
Public Function CreateAdAccount(ByVal sUserName As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal sFirstName As String, ByVal sLastName As String, ByVal sGroupName As String) As Boolean
   Dim bResult As Boolean = True
   Dim dirEntry As New DirectoryEntry(ADFullPath)

   SetCultureAndIdentity()

   ' 1. Create user account
   Dim adUsers As DirectoryEntries
   Dim newUser As DirectoryEntry

   If Not UserExists(sUserName) Then
      Try
         adUsers = dirEntry.Children
         newUser = adUsers.Add("CN=" & sUserName, "user")

         ' 2. Set properties
         SetProperty(newUser, "givenname", sFirstName)
         SetProperty(newUser, "sn", sLastName)
         SetProperty(newUser, "SAMAccountName", sUserName)
         SetProperty(newUser, "userPrincipalName", sUserName)
         SetProperty(newUser, "displayName", sFirstName & " " & sLastName)

         Try
            newUser.CommitChanges()
         Catch ex As Exception
            Err.Raise(4938, "clsSource", ex.Message)
         End Try
```

The error happens on this line: `newUser.CommitChanges()`

i can't seem to figure out why it keeps breaking. i tried to login as the admin in to AD and create a new user. it worked fine...

Comment: Under what context does the code actually run as? Is this a web application/windows app? If it is running as a web app the context under which the web application is running, i.e. the app pool might not have sufficient privileges to AD

Comment: it is a web application. i didn't realize i had to put it in a different app pool... i'll look now. do i set pool permissions in IIS or in AD?

Comment: Well you *dont* have to put it in a different app pool, you have a couple of options, you could impersonate identity before you make the call and make no changes to the app pool settings, or you could create a separate app pool and make that app pool run under the context of a domain account that has privileges to AD, Eitherways, since the web application is going to query ad, the security context underwhich the call is made needs to have appropriate rights, there are a couple of different ways to approach this.

Comment: i added "impersonate" to my web config, looks like it worked :)

Comment: Also just so you know, now the whole app will be running under the credentials of the accessing user, this may not be desirable in some cases, just as an fyi.

Comment: And **what exactly** does the exception give you?? Codes? Message?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on **.NET 3.5** and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily create new users:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// create a new user
UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// define properties
newUser.GivenName = sFirstName;
newUser.Surname = sLastName;
newUser.SamAccountName = sUserName;
newUser.UserPrincipalName = sUserName;
newUser.DisplayName = sFirstName + " " + sLastName;

// save changes
newUser.Save();
```

I'm not sure what you have in `sUserName` - but the `.UserPrincipalName` property should always be something like `someuser@somedomain.com` - does your user name contain such a value? If not - maybe try to use that kind of a notation for your user principal name.

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD: